# Some years have a siman, what does it mean?

Tags: number, calendar, symbols-symbology

I saw on a calendar that each year has a siman, for example 5772 has the siman 517.

Here are the simanim for the next few years:

- 5773: 203
- 5774: 1523
- 5775: 517
- 5776: 1217

Does anyone know the meaning of the siman? I was thinking about a description of the year but I can't find relevant things.

Comment: Why "Some years"?

Comment: can you tell us the name of the calendar?

Comment: @Menachem it's a calendar edited by a shul in Paris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that it means as follows:

> First Day of Rosh Hashanah = Thursday = 5
>
> One Adar (i.e., non-leap-year) = 1
>
> First Day of Pesach = Shabbos = 7

From this information you could extrapolate everything else in the year.

I've never seen this particular system before, but it makes sense.

Comment: this my first idea but I see this siman on an other year for which the first day of Rosh Hashanah is a Monday :(

Comment: The "1" in the second place actually means that it's a "kesidran" year, where the months are sequentially 30 and 29 days; thus, Cheshvan had 29 and Kislev 30. ("0" would mean a "chaseirah" year, where both of them are 29 days; "2" is a "malei" year, where both have 30. That's the system used in the tables in Leo Levi's *Jewish Chrononomy*.)

Comment: Interesting, @Alex! That's not a very intuitive system, if you ask me.

Comment: @allced - what was the other year that had this siman?

Comment: @Dave: here the simanim for the next years: **5772**: 517  **5773**: 203  **5774**: 1523  **5775**: 517  **5776**: 1217

Comment: Thanks to Dave, we get the first and third number. Thanks to Alex, we get the second one. Maybe for a 4 numbers siman, the first indicates that the year contains 2 Adar ?

Comment: This was the system we used when studying the calendar, except that we used Hebrew letters, so instead of 0, 1, or 2 to determine Cheshvan and Kislev, we used *kaf, ches,* and *shin* (for *"k'sidran", "chaserim",* and *"sh'leimim"*). The [Tur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43059&st=&pgnum=405) used the same system, except that he only used the first two letters (for R"H and Cheshvan/Kislev).

Comment: @allced: seems like they goofed up something, then, because for 5776 the siman should correctly be 1227 - it's a malei year. (And yeah, I've never heard of a four-letter or -number siman either.)